# Connect the docker container to an RDS db

Tags: python, docker, pymysql

I have a docker container on a EC2 if i run the code directly in EC2 everything is fine, but when the docker is running it throws the next error

> (1045, "Access denied for user 'xxxxx'@'xxxx' (using password: YES)")

I know that's an error in the connection, but is the same user, password and ip of the EC2.

I execute the docker image with network in host mode and the problem persist

I'm using a python image and pymysql to conect to my db

This is exactly my problem [Accessing RDS from within a Docker container not getting through security group?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32893876/accessing-rds-from-within-a-docker-container-not-getting-through-security-group)

Comment: Allow the ip address 
GRANT SELECT, INSERT ON mydatabase.* TO 'root'@'<ip>';

Comment: The ip already has  permission and keep the same error

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My solution was to use ECS and avoid ec2 to run the docker image